# Using autofs to mount under each users' home directory

Tags: centos, autofs

*(crosspost from SF, where I wasn't getting much joy)*

I have a CentOS 6.2 box up and running and have configured autofs to automount Windows shares under a /mydomain folder, using various howtos on the internet.  Specifically, I have three files:

### /etc/auto.master

```
# ...
/mydomain   /etc/auto.mydomain --timeout=60
# ...
```

### /etc/auto.mydomain

```
* -fstype=autofs,-DSERVER=& file:/etc/auto.mydomain.sub
```

### /etc/auto.mydomain.sub

```
* -fstype=cifs,uid=${UID},gid=${EUID},credentials=${HOME}/.smb/mydomain ://${SERVER}/&
```

This works and allows each user to specify their own credentials in a file under their home directory.

However, the mounts they create are then available to everyone, with the original user's credentials, until the timeout is reached.  This is less than ideal, so I've been looking at trying to do one of the following:

1. Configure autofs so that the mounts are local to each user but under the same path, so they can each simultaneously access `/mydomain/server1` with their own credentials
2. Configure autofs so that the mount points are under each users' home folder, so they can each simultaneously access `~/mydomain/server1` with their own credentials
3. Configure autofs so that the mounts are under a user-named folder, so they can simultaneously access `/mydomain/$USER/server1` with their own credentials (but I would also need to ensure that `/mydomain/$USER` is 0700 to the given $USER)

So far, I can't see any way of doing #1, but for #2 or #3, I've tried changing the entry in /etc/auto.master so that the key is either `${HOME}/mydomain` or `/mydomain/${USER}`, but neither have worked (the first showed no matching entry in `/var/log/messages` and the second did not appear to do the variable substitution).

Am I missing something obvious?

(PS: Bonus props if you can provide a way to avoid the need for a plain-text credentials file -- maybe a straight prompt for username/domain/password, or maybe even some kerberos magic?)

(PPS: I have looked briefly at [smbnetfs](http://sourceforge.net/projects/smbnetfs/), but I couldn't get it to configure/make -- it asks for `fuse >= 2.6` even though I have v2.8.3 according to `fusermount --version` -- and I couldn't find a released version for `yum install`)

(PPPS: I also briefly looked at the supplied `/etc/auto.smb` but it looked like it would suffer the same sharing issues?)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've done a lot of work with `autofs` and mounting a variety of different types of resources using it. You can check out the [man page](http://linux.die.net/man/5/autofs) for `autofs` which does answer some of your questions if you can keep straight that when they're referring to `$USER` in the documentation, they're referring to the user that's running the `autofs` daemon. These are the variables that you get by default:

```
Variable Substitution

The following special variables will be substituted in the key and location fields of an automounter map if prefixed with $ as customary from shell scripts (Curly braces can be used to separate the field name):
ARCH    Architecture (uname -m)
CPU    Processor Type
HOST    Hostname (uname -n)
OSNAME    Operating System (uname -s)
OSREL    Release of OS (uname -r)
OSVERS    Version of OS (uname -v)
autofs provides additional variables that are set based on the user requesting the mount:

USER    The user login name
UID    The user login ID
GROUP    The user group name
GID    The user group ID
HOME    The user home directory
HOST    Hostname (uname -n)
Additional entries can be defined with the -Dvariable=Value map-option to automount(8).
```

You'd probably be tempted to use the `-DUSER=$USER` but this will only set `$USER` inside the `autofs` map file to the user that started the `autofs` daemon. The daemon is usually owned by a user such as `root` or a `chrooted` user specifically setup for `autofs`.

**NOTE #1:** a `autofs` file is comprised of a `key` and a `value`. The variables are only allowed for use within the `value` portion of a entry.

**NOTE #2:** If the `-D=...` switch does not override a built-in variable then `$USER` or `$UID` would contain the value of the person's `$USER` & `$UID` that is accessing the mount.

#### Limiting access to the CIFS share

Regarding your question of how to limit access to a `CIFS` mount, I don't see a way to accomplish this with `autofs`.

The credentials used to mount a `CIFS` share are used throughout the duration that the share is mounted. In effect, `autofs`, running it's daemon `automount` as say `root`, is "equivalent" to the credentials of the `CIFS` user.

This isn't what I would consider typical behavior for `autofs` and is a by-product of using `mount.cifs`. Typical `autofs` behavior would respect the permissions on the other end of the mount, whereas with `mount.cifs` it does not.

#### Bottom-line

I think you're out of luck accomplishing your setup using autofs. I think you're going to have to use `fuse` if you truly want each user to be accessing `CIFS` shares using their own credentials.

Comment: Thanks for this.  Given `autofs provides additional variables that are set based on the user requesting the mount`, does that not mean `$USER` is already understood by autofs to be the guy who just `cd`'d into the path?  Same with `$HOME`, I'd have thought.  Is *that* the bit I am misunderstanding?  Could it be more that the variable substitution cannot take place in the *path* part of the config file, only in the *response* part?  So I can automount with config: `/mydomain    /etc/auto.mydomain --timeout=60` but I can't with config: `$HOME/mydomain    /etc/auto.mydomain --timeout=60`?

Comment: One other approach you can take is that the map files can be scripts, so you can have a program/script generate the output as long as it conforms to the `key` & `value` syntax. Here's an example: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2036409

Comment: Yes my understanding is that those variables can only be used on the right side (the value) of the auto map files. The left side being the key. I've added additional notes to my answer to try and clear up what I was saying regarding the variables.

Comment: This is a matter of clarity in documentation then, I guess:  the man line `The following special variables will be substituted in the *key and location fields* of an automounter map if prefixed` does not apply to the per-user variables that follow the man line `autofs provides additional variables that are set based on the user requesting the mount`.  The script approach might be interesting, though.  I'll see if I can wrap my head around coercing the logic into a working script...

Comment: Agreed. Other than FUSE, I think you're only other option will be the script for getting more elaborate setups.

Comment: Have you used scripts before?  I get that you have to print the resultant autofs 'file' to stdout, but can it spit stderr to the end-user and read user input with `read var` (I'm thinking specifically about prompting for credentials, or at least reporting failure)?  Or is the script run in a background process somewhere?

Comment: I believe it's background only. The script can merely dynamically generate the key,values that would normally be returned similar to a text file that contains the automount maps. I don't believe the users are able to interact with it in any way.

Answer (score 2):

You can force the permissions set on the CIFS mount with the `file_mode` and `dir_mode` options, in conjunction with the `uid=${USER}` setting you were already using, giving an automount map line of something like this:

```
* -fstype=cifs,uid=${UID},gid=${EUID},file_mode=0600,dir_mode=0700,credentials=${HOME}/.smb/mydomain ://${SERVER}/&
```

The mounted filesystem will then be owned by the user, and the permissions set to disallow access to all other users.  I've just tried this and it appears to work fine  :)

You may want to set `file_mode=0700` if there are executables you expect to be able to run stored on the share.  My example removes the execute permission as that was the behaviour I wanted.

*Note: This option may not have existed at the time the question was asked, but it does now!*

Answer (score 0):

Using Samba:

In `/etc/auto.home`:

```
*       -fstype=cifs,credentials=/etc/smbcreds.& ://MYSERVERIP/homes
```

You will need is to store all users and passwords in an independent file `/etc/smbcreds`

The last part of the line will mount via samba.

Using NFS:

In /etc/auto.home: (for NFS)

```
*       MYSERVERIP:/home/&
```